# FW/1 SES and IIS Rewrites

Tags: iis, coldfusion, url-rewriting, fw1

I've just started with FW/1 and I'm just trying to get things working but not having much luck with the SES urls.

So in `Application.cfc` I'm turning SES urls on and removing `index.cfm` I have:

```
generateSES = true
SESOmitIndex = true
```

in my `main.cfc` I have 2 items `default` and `seconditem`:

```
public void function default( rc ) {
    rc.when = now();
    variables.fw.service( 'formatter.longdate', 'today' );
}

public void function seconditem( rc ) {
    rc.when = now();
    variables.fw.service( 'formatter.longdate', 'today' );
}
```

I have the views for each item in `main.cfc` and I have this rewrite rule in my `web.config` file

```
<rule name="Insert index.cfm" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm/{PATH_INFO}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

**So here's the issue:**

When I go to `http://dev.dev/main/default` - It calls `main.default`

When I go to `http://dev.dev/main/seconditem` - It calls `main.default` not `main.seconditem`

If I add the `index.cfm` back in:

When I go to `http://dev.dev/index.cfm/main/default` - It calls `main.default`

When I go to `http://dev.dev/index.cfm/main/seconditem` - It calls `main.seconditem`

Looking at my IIS logs the URL is getting rewritten to include `index.cfm`:

```
2014-02-19 23:13:44 GET /index.cfm/main/default - 80
2014-02-19 23:13:53 GET /index.cfm/main/seconditem - 80
```

So based on the IIS logs telling me the rewrite is working, why when I go to the url without the `index.cfm` it always goes to `main.default`?

I've also tried with different controllers where:

`http://dev.dev/users/default` - goes to `main.default`

but:

`http://dev.dev/index.cfm/users/default` - goes to `users.default`

And the IIS logs show this for both requests:

```
2014-02-19 23:20:47 GET /index.cfm/users - 80
2014-02-19 23:21:37 GET /index.cfm/users - 80
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rewrite rule I use on a FW/1 project

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^((?!\.).)*$|(\.cfm)$" />
            <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/(assets|scratch|remote|index.cfm|extensions)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The second `<add>` block is used to list directories or files I do not want rewritten.

Comment: Hi Scott, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I just get a 404 Not Found error when going to anything but `http://dev.dev/`. So going to `http://dev.dev/main/default` or `http://dev.dev/main/seconditem` both throw the 404. I added `logRewrittenUrl="true"` to your rule and the IIS logs show `GET /main/seconditem - 80` so it's not adding the `/index.cfm/` at all.

Comment: OK I've figured out what was going on, it's only taken 2 days :) I didn't re-run the ColdFusion Web Server Configuration Tool after installing the last update. So I did that and all is now working. Thanks for posting you rewrite rule.